# Python no module named module_name

Tags: python, matplotlib, raspbian

I know this question has been asked a lot on here. When I run this code I get the above error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

from random_walk import * 

#Make a random walk and plot the points 
rw = RandomWalk()
rw.fill_walk()

plt.scatter(rw.x_values, rw.y_values, s = 15)
plt.show()
```

I tried coding the file(maybe not correctly though). I also tried rewriting my code in multiple ways but none of the solutions that I found helped. And I did try writing out the path to random_walk.py but that oddly didn't help.  matplotlib is installed in Python 3.5 and 2.7. I am using Raspbian on a Rasp Pi 3 and the IDE is Geany. I should mention that this file and random_walk.py are in the same folder. (I've also tried the code without the * at from random_walk import and used the class name from the file and still got the same error)

Answer (score 0):

A python package should contain an `__init__.py` file, so you can import things around. Something like:

```
your_module/
  __init__.py (can be empty)
  __main__.py (your script with imports)
  random_walk.py
```

Refer to:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages